# Cross Covariance Matrix of Multidimensional Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, markov-process, covariance, stochastic-differential-equations

The multivariate Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process is defined as the following
\begin{equation}
    dX(t) = - I_p X(t) dt + \sqrt{2}I_p dW(t)
\end{equation}
where $I_p$ is an $p \times p$ identity matrix, and $W(t)$ is an $p$-dimensional standard Wiener process. Let $X(0)$ be standard $p$-dimensional Gaussian.

I am looking for the unconditional cross covariance matrix $\text{E}(X(0)X(t))$. Could anyone please help me with this? As of now, I have only found cross-covariance matrix conditioning on $X(0)$, $\text{E}(X(s)X(t)|X(0)=x)$, on Page 16 in "Review of Statistical Arbitrage, Cointegration, and Multivariate Ornstein-Uhlenbeck" or in Theorem 2 in "Alternative way to derive the distribution of the multivariate Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process".

I am not sure if unconditional cross covariance follows from these. In Theorem 2, $\text{E}(X(s)X(t)|X(0)=x)$ gets $0$ if one of $s$ or $t$ is $0$. "Mathematical properties" in [Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process) gives the solution for the one-dimensional case. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think it might be here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.04961.pdf